# Address book empty after migration from Outlook 2003 to Outlook 2010

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, import

After a new Windows XP installation on a notebook I imported the old Outlook 2003 Outlook.pst file into Outlook 2010. All the old emails and folders showed up, but not so the addressbook which is empty.

The mail accounts are several quite large IMAP accounts. The backup is an 1:1 hd image of the old installation which I access via USB.

How can I access the old addresses?

Comment: To avoid misleading answers, you might want to clarify what you mean by "address book" - are you talking about your own contacts folder, or some coroprate address book (on Exchange this would be the GAL)?

Comment: @AdamV: I think you'll find that esc1729 was able to resolve their own problem.  See the first comment to my answer below.

Comment: D'oh! Not sure how I came across this old thread. Never mind!

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually looking in your contacts folder, or clicking on the addres bbok button (or To button on a new email)?

It might be that your Contacts have migrated properly but the Contacts folder is not marked to be used as an Outlook address book - right click on Contacts, choose Properties > outlook address book > tick the box

Answer (score -1):

Address books in Outlook are a weird beast. They actually exist outside of Outlook and its main data files, in the form of PAB (or WAB) files.  Search your backup image for files with those extensions. You should find at least one that is larger than the others and was modified more recently.  That will be your old address book file.  Try importing it in Outlook (e.g. in Outlook 2007 it's File > Import and Export > Import from another program or file > Personal Address Book - for PAB files).  But often this external address book is simply composed of items from your Outlook Contacts folder.  If you look at the related options in the Address Book menus and in the main Outlook options, you'll find ways to make this connection.  If your Outlook Contacts folder is current, you may only need to set up the Address Book so that it is getting its content from there.

Comment: The addresses were burried in the original Outlook.pst file. For some reason it did not import on the first take, but my colleague had a second look on it and got it working. Thank you anyway, boot13 for your answer!

Comment: I think you are confusing Outlook and Outlook Express, or referring to very old versions of Outlook. Express used to use the Windows Address Book mechanism when it was integrated, I have some dim recollection of PABs coming up in Outlook but a very long time ago, certainly not 2003 era. Contacts are just a folder in the pst file or Exchange mailbox, not another external file, as far as my recent memory serves.

Comment: @AdamV: I take it that your comment was directed at my answer rather than the comment immediately above yours?  However, it appears that you are correct insofar as Outlook and the Address Book are concerned.  I never noticed that Microsoft had changed this, but I'm glad they did!